# GET request on the route https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning and then clean the object

Tags: php

This is the practice code:

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r(json_decode($data, true));
?>
```

and I tried this

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r(json_decode($data, true));

echo "<pre>" . print_r($newdata, 1) . "</pre>";

foreach ($newdata as $key => $value) {

if (!is_array($value)) {

  echo "key: " . $key . " Value: " . $value . "<br>";
  if (!empty($value)) && $value !== "-" && $value !== "N/A") {
    $new_array[$key] = $value;
  }
}

else {
  foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
    if (!empty($v) && $v !== "-" && $v !== "N/A") {
      $new_array[$key][$k] = $v;
    }
  }
}

}
echo "<pre>" . print_r($new_array, 1) . "</pre>";
?>
```

although i am unable to succeeded

To perform a GET request on the route https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning and then clean the object according to the following rules: Remove all keys that have values of N/A, -, or empty strings. If one of these values appear in an array, remove that single item from the array. Then console log the modified object as a string.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Your data is in `$data`, but you're trying to loop over `$newdata` so... yeah, obviously that's not gonna work.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I tried removing the new and add $data alone still no use

Answer (score 2):

Can be done with recursive function as follow:

```
function clean_obj($data) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
            if ($val == 'N/A' || $val == '-' || $val == '') {
                unset($data[$key]);
            }
            if (is_array($val)) {
                $data[$key] = clean_obj($val);
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}


$ch = curl_init('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$newData = json_decode($data, true);
$new_array=clean_obj($newData);
echo "<pre>" . print_r($new_array, 1) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: still wrong it prints the N/A and null space

Comment: @Jobs, just copied the code and ran on local server and did not find any N/A or blank space

Comment: output : {"name":{"first":"Daniel","last":"Smith"},"age":45}

Comment: @Jobs: where is N/A or blank space in that output?
I am getting this output:
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [first] => Robert
            [last] => Smith
        )

    [age] => 25
    [hobbies] => Array
        (
            [0] => running
            [1] => coding
        )

    [education] => Array
        (
            [college] => Yale
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ch = curl_init('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$newData = json_decode($data, true);

filterNAPlusEmptyStrings($newData);

function filterNAPlusEmptyStrings(&$newData) {
    foreach ($newData as $key => $value ) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            filterNAPlusEmptyStrings($value);
        }
        if ($value === '' || $value === 'N/A' || $value ===  '-' ) {
            unset($newData[$key]);
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>" . print_r($newData, 1) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "filterNAPlusEmptyStrings" in /tmp/484541165/main.php on line 10 - Getting the above error @romankrut

Comment: I missed the ";", fixed. Could you try againg?

Comment: Tried that too still error  - syntax error, unexpected token "||" in /tmp/860768640/main.php on line 17

Comment: Could you use some IDE to find out the problem of syntax? I think you copied it incorrectly.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler 

I am try ing in this compiler please check once

Comment: Cmon dude. Just copy it correctly. Everything works https://prnt.sc/1xyvw70

Comment: In the PHP file, program to perform a GET request on the route https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning and then clean the object according to the following rules: Remove all keys that have values of N/A, -, or empty strings. If one of these values appear in an array, remove that single item from the array. Then console log the modified object as a string.

Comment: output : {"name":{"first":"Daniel","last":"Smith"},"age":45}

Comment: Replace echo "<pre>" . print_r($newData, 1) . "</pre>"; with echo json_decode($newData);
And also we here helping people to resolve some problems, and you are asking us to resolve the tasks insted of problem. You should google how to display array as json in php and stop asking not related question to this topic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:-

```
<?php

  // Your goal is to count how many items exist that have an age equal to or greater than 50, and print this final value.

  

    $ch = curl_init('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
    
      $json_data = json_decode($data, true);
      $items = explode(', ', $json_data['data']);
      $count = array_reduce($items, function ($count, $item) {
        if (strpos($item, 'age=') !== false) {
          $age = explode('=', $item)[1];
          if ($age >= 50) return $count + 1;
        }
        return $count;
      }, 0);
    
      print_r($count); // 128
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
$myArr = array();
    
foreach($arr as $keys => $values) {
  if(is_array($values)){
    $otherArr = array();
    foreach($values as $key=>$value){
      if (!($value == 'N/A' || $value == '-' || $value == ''))
        $otherArr[$key] = $value;
    }
    $myArr[$keys] = $otherArr;
  }
  else{
    if (!($values == 'N/A' || $values == '-' || $values == '')) 
      $myArr[$keys] = $values;
  }
}
print_r($myArr);
?>
```